# Sending response to the formpanel in gwt from servlet

Tags: gwt, servlets

I am calling servlet from the gwt client program and setting

```
final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"/uploadservlet2");
```

Now on submit complete I want to retrieve a parameter from the servlet in this event,

```
 form.addFormHandler(new FormHandler() {
      public void onSubmit(FormSubmitEvent event) {
        // This event is fired just before the form is submitted. We can take
        // this opportunity to perform validation.
                RootPanel.get().add(new Label("On submit"));
      }

      public void onSubmitComplete(FormSubmitCompleteEvent event) {
**///I want parameter here**
                RootPanel.get().add(new Label("On submiting complete"));
      }
    });
```

Please tell me how I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your onSubmitComplete:

```
public void onSubmitComplete(FormSubmitCompleteEvent event) {
String serverResponse = event.getResults();

}
```

you can let the server return HTML and put this in an HTML widget, or let the server return som JSON and parse this in GWT.